# Erro com intercerptors angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jwt

Estou tentando implementar um sistema de autenticação com Angular + json web token, porém quanto tento fazer um `$http.interceptors.push('nomeDo Interceptor')` apresenta erro na aplicação e no console do navegador não mostra nenhum erro.

Segue algumas partes do código.

#### O interceptor

```
angular.module('digApp').factory('authInterceptor', function(){
  return {
    request: function(config){
      console.log(config);
      return config;
    }
  }
});
```

#### A Config do interceptor

```
angular.module('digApp').config(function($httpProvider){
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push("authInterceptor");
});
```

por enquanto só estou exibindo o que vem da config, mas não está funcionado, a aplicação trava as requisições **http** que faz a **api**. E não mostra o **console.log()**, e nem carrega as views do **ng-view**;

Caso alguém tenha um bom tutorial de Sistema de login Angular  + jwt + nodejs fico grato.

Comment: Qual o erro que aparece no log? Podes colocar ele aqui?

Comment: Então esse é o problema no console do navegador não exibe nada,erro nenhum.Não lança qualquer exceção de erro dai nem sei como debugar isso.

Comment: Mas então que erro que aparece? Ou por que você acha que não funciona?

Comment: Não fuciona por que o angular não faz as requisições http, nem carrega as views, se eu remover o $http.interceptors.push(), ele volta a carregar as views normalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente ta tudo OK! Tente substituir o código do interceptor por esse

#### Interceptor.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('digApp')
        .factory('authInterceptor', authInterceptor);

    authInterceptor.$inject = ['$q'];

    function authInterceptor($q) {
        return {
            request: request,
            response: response,
            requestError: requestError,
            responseError: responseError
        };

        function request(config) {
            var url = config.url;
            return config;
        }

        function response(response) {
            var url = response.config.url;
            return response;
        }

        function requestError(rejection) {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }

        function responseError(rejection) {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: isso resolveu a questão que não não exibia o console.log(), mas se eu $injetar em alem $q, tipo preciso do $http, e do $localstorage volta a travar.Mas valeu vou vasculhar aqui ver onde estou errando.

Comment: acho que eu estou fazendo errado estou tentando fazer assim.

Comment: acho que eu estou fazendo errado estou tentando fazer assim:

`function request(config) {
            var url = config.url;
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'JWT' + store.get('id_token');
            return config;
        }`

Comment: Entendi! Você não vai conseguir modificar o header dessa forma. Retire o $http injetado no interceptor e tente adicionar essa Authorization ao header da seguinte forma : 
- `config.headers['Authorization'] = 'JWT';`

Comment: Então coloquei assim :

`function request(config) {
            var url = config.url;
            config.headers['Authorization'] = 'JWT '+ store.get('id_token');
            return config;
        }`

Acho que tem alguma coisa errada na api também.
coloquei ela no git se você quiser da uma olha fica a vontade.
https://github.com/asxpyre/piz.git

Comment: eu acho que o problema é esse store, retira ele do $inject e no headers deixa apenas o JWT por enquanto. Apenas pra fim de testes

Comment: Mesmo eu deixando só o jwt, não funciona, retorna 401. :(

Comment: Acho que já sei qual o problema, você tem que validar se é uma URL externa pra aplicar o modificação no reader:
           `var isRequest = false;
            if (url.indexOf('?') > -1) url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?'));
            if (url.lastIndexOf('http', 0) === 0) isRequest = true;
           if(isRequest){
                 config.headers['Authorization'] = 'JWT '+ store.get('id_token');
            }
            return config;`

Comment: Agora o erro mudou para `angular.min.js:118 Error: [$compile:tpload]`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47204/discussion-between-marcos-souza-and-luks-sys).